# How to create the ability to apply a generic data source class

Tags: c#, generics

This is maybe something I know how to do or have already done it in the past. For some reason I am drawing a blank on how to wrap my head around it. This is more for learning as well as trying to implement something in my app.

I am using a set of third party controls. These controls offer a lot of functionality which is great. However, I want to be able to create a custom object that handle the logic/properties for the datasource of this control.

For example, there is a spreadsheet like object that I am using. You supply the spreadsheet like object some data and it pulls in your data. The problem here is that you need to set the columns, their data types, and other formatting/events as well as some logic to spit the data back to the user.

```
List<CustomClassWithProperties> dataSource
```

The custom class has some properties that will be translated to the columns. Like ProductName, Price, SalesDepartment, DatePurchased etc. This can be done by supplying the spreadsheet the columns and their data types each time. I want to be able to create a helper class that you just supply a list, a visible column list, and an editable column list and the data will fill in without any other issues.

Using the above list, I would imagine something similar to this:

```
DataHelperClass dtHlpr = new DataHelperClass(List<CustomClassWithProperties> data, List<string> visibleColumns, List<string> editableColumns)
```

This data helper class will take the data input list as the spreadsheet data source. It would then take the visibleColumns list and use that to set the visible rows, same for editableColumns.

Where I am running into a mental block (long week) is when I want to be able to reuse this. Let's say I have a List that has completely different properties. I would want my constructor for the data helper to be able to handle any List I send to it. Looking at whatever code I can get to for the third party controls, it appears that their data source is of type object.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I am thinking it has to do with generics and some interface implementation. I just honestly cannot think of where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the class itself generic:

```
public class DataHelperClass<T>
{
    public DataHelperClass(List<T> data, ...) { ... }
}
```

```
DataHelperClass<CustomClassWithProperties> dtHlpr = new DataHelperClass<CustomClassWithProperties>(List<CustomClassWithProperties> data, List<string> visibleColumns, List<string> editableColumns)
```

You'd then perform your reflection against `typeof(T)`.

I'd also be tempted to use `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `List<T>` if possible, but that's a matter of preference, more or less.

This is similar to using a simple `List<object>`, except that it enforces that all objects in the list inherit from the same type (which might well be `object`), so you get some more type-checking than you otherwise would.

You mentioned interfaces, I don't see any reason here to include that (from what you've told us, at least), but you can certainly make a generic interface via the same syntax.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you. I know I have done it in the past I just could not remember. I really appreciate the help.